# How to create custom keyboard for Android that works with Talkback

Tags: android, keyboard, accessibility, talkback

We are trying to develop a custom keyboard on Android for the visually impaired people.  Creating the keyboard is easy, but we have no clue how to make it accessible, say for instance, interacting with TalkBack.  In fact, other than the native Google keyboard, we have not seen any custom keyboard that can work with TalkBack.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: SO is really for code questions - like 'why doesn't this code do X', not so much for broad implementation strategies.

Answer (score 2):

The LatinIME implements a lift-to-type interaction model, which is a special case, but otherwise interacts with accessibility services the same way that any application would by populating AccessibilityEvents and AccessibilityNodeInfos.

If your keyboard is implemented as a custom view, you should read up on [ExploreByTouchHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/ExploreByTouchHelper.html) and consider watching the Google I/O 2013 presentation on custom view accessibility.

In general, you should take a look at the LatinIME's [accessibility components](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/+/master/java/src/com/android/inputmethod/accessibility/) which cover [lift-to-type interaction (lines 206-259)](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/+/master/java/src/com/android/inputmethod/accessibility/AccessibleKeyboardViewProxy.java#206) as well as implementing a [node provider](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/+/master/java/src/com/android/inputmethod/accessibility/AccessibilityEntityProvider.java) (simplified if you are using ExploreByTouchHelper).

Comment: Thanks alanv for the great help. We run into a lot of problems compiling the LatinIME source, will definitely give it another go.